# How can I use Promises in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have 2 files
1. api_service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from 'aurelia-http-client';
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";
import { ObserverLocator } from "aurelia-binding";

@autoinject()
export class ApiServices {
    private app_url = 'http://example.com/';
    private host = 'http://api.example.com:8080';

    constructor(private store: Store, private client: HttpClient, private observerLocator: ObserverLocator) { }

    GetInstallationId() {
        let url = this.host + "/1/api/iid";
        let iid;
        this.client.get(url)
            .catch((err) => { })
            .then(res => {
                let response = JSON.parse(res.response);
                iid = response.iid;
            });
        return iid;
    }
}
```

here I am trying to get some value from the server and in the HTTP response, I can see that I am getting it.

2. board_services.ts

```js
import { Store } from './localstorage_service';
import { ApiServices } from './api_service';
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";
import { ObserverLocator } from "aurelia-binding";

@autoinject()
export class AppServices {
 private installation_ID: string;

 constructor(private store: Store, private apiServices: ApiServices, private observerLocator: ObserverLocator) { }

 getInstallationID() {
  const iid = this.store.getValue('installation_ID');
  console.log("iid = " + iid);
  if (iid && iid != undefined) {
   console.log('inside if iid');
   // this.installation_ID = this.apiServices.GetInstallationId();
   this.installation_ID = iid;
  } else {
   console.log('inside else iid');
   this.installation_ID = this.apiServices.GetInstallationId();
  }
  this.store.setValue('installation_ID', this.installation_ID);
  console.log("after if condition iid = " + iid);
  return this.installation_ID;
 }
}
```

here in this code I'm calling the function `GetInstallationId()` from `api_services.ts` but it is not waiting for the `http request` to complete. Is there a way to make the statement in the next statement execute after the `GetInstallationId()` is executed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer: you need to support asynchronous behavior.

You may do this via (a) [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and/or (b) [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).  The former is [supported in all browsers except IE 11](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) and there are polyfills [like this one](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) if you need to support IE 11.  The latter is currently not supported in IE at all and as it requires new JS keywords/syntax must be used with a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

This answer will use Promises as they have fewer dependencies than async/await.  The snippets below have been updated to use Promises -- look for the comments like:

`// REPLACED THIS LINE` ... `// WITH THIS LINE`

and

`// ADDED THIS LINE`

which identify the updates.

1. `GetInstallationId` is an asynchronous function and must return a promise.

   ```
   class ApiServices { 
       ... 
       GetInstallationId() {
           let url = this.host + "/1/api/iid";
           return new Promise(function(accept, reject) {                
               let iid;
               this.client.get(url)
                   .catch((err) => { })
                   .then(res => {
                       let response = JSON.parse(res.response);
                       // REPLACED THIS LINE
                       // iid = response.iid;
                       // WITH THIS LINE which accepts the promise
                       accept(response.iid);
                   })
                   // ADDED THIS LINE to catch any errors 
                   // e.g. when invalid response received
                   .catch(reject);        
           });
       }

   }
   ```
2. Because `getInstallationID` calls `GetInstallationId`, it too must return a promise.  This example defines a separate function, `handler`, which is then bound via `.bind(this)` to ensure that whenever the function is executed, `this` will always refer back to the correct ApiService object.

   ```
   class AppServices {
       ...
       getInstallationID() {

     function handler(accept, reject) {
       const iid = this.store.getValue('installation_ID');
       console.log("iid = " + iid);
       if (iid && iid != undefined) {
           console.log('inside if iid');
           // this.installation_ID = this.apiServices.GetInstallationId();
           this.installation_ID = iid;
       } else {
           console.log('inside else iid');
           // REPLACED THIS LINE
           // this.installation_ID = this.apiServices.GetInstallationId();
           // WITH THIS LINE
           this.apiServices.GetInstallationId().then(accept,reject);
       }
       this.store.setValue('installation_ID', this.installation_ID);
       console.log("after if condition iid = " + iid);
       // REPLACED THIS LINE
       // return this.installation_ID;
       // WITH THIS LINE
       accept(this.installation_ID); 
     };

     return new Promise(handler.bind(this));        
   }        
   ...


   }
   ```

   > The above function is just one example which will work cross browser.   Another solution which requires ES6 support and/or transpilation is to use arrow functions:

   ```
       //
       // Arrow function version
       //
   class AppServices {
       ...
       getInstallationID() {
         // NOTE the => which is shorthand for `(function (accept,reject) {...}).bind(this)`
         return new Promise((accept, reject) => {
           const iid = this.store.getValue('installation_ID');
           console.log("iid = " + iid);
           if (iid && iid != undefined) {
               console.log('inside if iid');
               // this.installation_ID = this.apiServices.GetInstallationId();
               this.installation_ID = iid;
           } else {
               console.log('inside else iid');
               // REPLACED THIS LINE
               // this.installation_ID = this.apiServices.GetInstallationId();
               // WITH THIS LINE
               this.apiServices.GetInstallationId().then(accept,reject);
           }
           this.store.setValue('installation_ID', this.installation_ID);
           console.log("after if condition iid = " + iid);
           // REPLACED THIS LINE
           // return this.installation_ID;
           // WITH THIS LINE
           accept(this.installation_ID); 
         });        
       }        
       ...
   }
   ```

With the above refactoring, you can now call `getInstallationID()` from e.g. another view model like this:

```
import {AppServices} from '...';
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
@autoinject()
export class SomeViewModel {
    constructor(appServices) {
        this.appServices = appServices;
    }

    callGetInstallationId() {

        this.appServices.getInstallationID().then(function(id) {
            // the ID that is passed here is the one that is `accept`ed.
            // ie. if AppServices.getInstallationID calls accept('123'), then 
            // the '123' will be passed to this function as the first argument
        }, function(e) {
            // this function will be called if AppServices.getInstallationID
            // calls reject.  e will be the Error object, if any, that is passed
            // to the reject method.
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man. I guess I have a lot more to learn about javascript. Can you suggest me some sites where I can look into the latest techs in front end development?

Comment: I can not use `this.installation_ID` inside 
`new Promise(function(accept, reject) {  }` it is saying that its undefined.
the code is 
`
`

Comment: Re: tutorials, at this point you should read about ES6 javascript; something like this:  http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial/  also it's worthwhile to checkout Typescript https://www.typescriptlang.org/ and then decide which way you want to go.  Note this is just language, then you have to think about frameworks like Aurelia, React, Angular, etc.  Good luck!

Comment: @BimalmithranP.B sorry about that! I've updated the code with two examples ( one using Function.bind and one with arrow functions ). If you're using a transpiler like Babel you should definitely use arrow functions.   The main changes were: function 1: move let url to function scope vs promise function scope ( which has proper 'this' context ). function 2: wrapped the function declaration in a .bind(this) which ensures and added arrow function example.